# How can I keep same object but replace only one property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, lodash

Let's say this is my array of objects:

```
let data = [{
              firstname: 'John',
              lastname: 'Doe'
             },
             {
              firstname: 'Jane',
              lastname: '- Doe'
             }]
```

Now, I want to make a new object, but where `- Doe` is I need to remove this part `-` and leave only `Doe`.

I have tried this:

`let pollyData = data.map(item => _.mapValues(item, val => val.lastname.split('- ').pop()))`

However, I get `undefined`.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Will you always have object properties containing exactly `lastname: '- Doe'` that you wan't to replace, or will they instead always match some sort of pattern, or instance starting with a dash and a space?

Comment: You want to remove " - " from Doe value or make it to whole array of objects, you are not specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate with Array#map. Check if an object includes a `lastname` with a dash. If so create a new object with a cleaned lastname. If not return the original object.

Note: I've used [object spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) to replace the `lastname`. If not supported by your build stack, you can use `Object.assign({}, obj, { lastname: obj.lastname.replace(/^-\s+/, '') })` instead.

```js
const data = [{
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname: 'Doe'
  },
  {
    firstname: 'Jane',
    lastname: '- Doe'
  }
];

const result = data.map((obj) => obj.lastname.includes('-') ? ({
  ...obj,
  lastname: obj.lastname.replace(/^-\s+/, '')
}) : obj);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex and `array#map`

```js
let data = [{ firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Doe' }, { firstname: 'Jane', lastname: '- Doe' }];
var result = data.map(({firstname, lastname}) => 
  ({firstname, lastname: lastname.replace(/^\s*\-\s*/g, '')})
);
console.log(result);
```